# How to use variable in chart.apis.google link for QR Code

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I installed BI Publisher on Windows 10 and create RTF File through XML. Set variable on Column Field like

```
<?NO?>
```

I insert sample Image in RTF File and add google api link on image ALT TEXT option

```
url:{'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=10'}
```

When execute through BI Publisher with PDF Option and scan QR Code then return output 10.

Now I want to add variable from above column into chart apis google link

```
<?NO?>
```

How to add variable?

Answer (score 0):

**For Google generated QR Codes**

You can use the `concat` function in BI Publisher.

Example XML

```
<test_header>
<test_row>
<row_num>1</row_num>
<value>TESTA</value>
</test_row>
<test_row>
<row_num>2</row_num>
<value>TESTB</value>
</test_row>
</test_header>
```

Example Template with temporary image:

[image: Example RTF Template]

Image Alt Text, where I'm using the `value` element

```
url:{concat('https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=500x500&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl=',value)}
```

Make sure to URL encode the data if you want spaces in the output.

**For built in chart support, read the BI Publisher user guide on charts:**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10415_01/doc/bi.1013/e12187/T421739T481157.htm#4535315

**For dynamic QR Codes, without going to an external server, it gets pretty complex:**

https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/quick-quips-on-qr-codes